# numpy. Как инициализировать состояние в random

Tags: python, случайные-числа, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Не получается инициализировать начальное состояние в `random` библиотеки numpy. Я пробовал устанавливать как seed, так и RandomState. Но, увы, ничего не выходит.

Первый запуск:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed = 42
np.random.RandomState = 42

print(np.random.random(1))
print(np.random.random(1))
```

> [ 0.11532686]
>
> [ 0.72154268]

Второй запуск

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed = 42
np.random.RandomState = 42

print(np.random.random(1))
print(np.random.random(1))
```

> [ 0.02857089]
>
> [ 0.14296982]

Как видно, получаем различные значения. А значит, начальные состояния различные.

Передать аргумент, как функции, у меня не получилось по непонятным для меня причинам:

Раз:

```
np.random.seed(42)
```

Два:

```
np.random.RandomState(42)
```

В каждом из двух случаев, я получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-182f47c09b69> in <module>()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 
----> 5 np.random.seed(42)
      6 np.random.RandomState(42)
      7 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Хотя [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994423/difference-between-np-random-seed-and-np-random-randomstate) всё прекрасно, судя по всему, работает.

Замечу, что я использую `jupyter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.random.seed = 42
np.random.RandomState = 42
```

Вы только что переопределили функции целочисленными значениями. Python вам об этом и сообщил:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

**После** переопределения вызов `np.random.seed(42)` - эквивалентен вызову:

```
In [7]: 42(42)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4f6413703d8c> in <module>()
----> 1 42(42)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Решение:

```
np.random.seed(42)
```

или

```
np.random.RandomState(42)
```

вместо:

```
np.random.seed = 42
np.random.RandomState = 42
```

Comment: Так нет же, я `np.random.RandomState(42)` делаю в самом начале.  Именно там наступает ругань

Comment: @hedgehogues, уберите из кода перезапись/переопределение функций и __перезапустите__ `jupyter`...